Is this class of indicator functions Donsker?
Consider the following class of indicator functions $\mathcal{F}=\{1_{f(x,\xi)\leq 0}: x\in \mathcal{X}\}$, where $\xi$ is a random vector, $\mathcal{X}\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is a compact set. We may assume that $f(x,\xi)$ is jointly continuous in $(x,\xi)$ for all $x\in \mathcal{X}$ and all realisations of $\xi$. You may also assume that $f$ is convex in $x$, if it helps.
Is $\mathcal{F}$ a Donsker class, for any possible distirbutions of $\xi$?
